# How to access a different console, such as writing to its input buffer

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, windows-console

I want to provide input to an application that is attached to a different console. For example, in the following picture, how would I write to the input of the console on the left-hand side from the console on the right-hand side?

[image: console windows example]

Comment: There are -many- ways to do this. When you have code that you are trying to make work, post it on SO. See the guidelines about posting on SO at https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: This cannot be implemented with CMD shell commands. You have to write a small program in C, Python, etc -- as long as the language or an available library allows access to the Windows API. One approach is to call `AttachConsole(targetPid)` and `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`. Then write key events to the input handle via `WriteConsoleInputW`.

Comment: You asked the same question seven (7) hours before this one. Right?

Comment: If the utility program itself is a console app, you have to first create a child process that simply waits forever. This is to keep a reference to the current console in order to re-attach to it. This can be an instance of the utility with a private command-line option that makes it wait. Then to access the other console, first detach via `FreeConsole()`.  At the end, re-attach to the original console via `FreeConsole()` and `AttachConsole(child_pid)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want IPC (Inter Process Communication) and there's many ways to do that. You can see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) for a more detailed explanation of your options.